Unable to read chunk in lidR catalog_apply
I try to use the LAScatalog processing engine function (catalog_apply()) to run the function mesure_roads() of ALSroads (my area has 4000 lidar tiles with a surface area of 1 km² so I can't have one big DEM which would be 40+ GO), but I think the catalog_apply() function just doesn't extract any las data.
I am not able to run this reproductible example which is located on this page : https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/catalog_apply.html
Here it is with a slightly modified version where I can extract in my global environment the "las" and "chunk" objects :
## =========================================================================
## Example 1: detect all the tree tops over an entire catalog
## (this is basically a reproduction of the existing function 'locate_trees')
## =========================================================================

# 1. Build the user-defined function that analyzes each chunk of the catalog.
# The function's first argument is a LAScluster object. The other arguments can be freely
# chosen by the users.
my_tree_detection_method <- function(chunk, ws)
{
  # The chunk argument is a LAScluster object. The users do not need to know how it works.
  # readLAS will load the region of interest (chunk) with a buffer around it, taking advantage of
  # point cloud indexation if possible. The filter and select options are propagated automatically
  las <<- readLAS(chunk)
  chunk_temp <<- chunk
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  
  # Find the tree tops using a user-developed method
  # (here simply a LMF for the example).
  ttops <- locate_trees(las, lmf(ws))
  
  # ttops is an sf object that contains the tree tops in our region of interest
  # plus the trees tops in the buffered area. We need to remove the buffer otherwise we will get
  # some trees more than once.
  bbox  <- st_bbox(chunk)
  ttops <- sf::st_crop(ttops, bbox)
  return(ttops)
}

# 2. Build a collection of file
# (here, a single file LAScatalog for the purposes of this simple example).
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
ctg <- readLAScatalog(LASfile)
plot(ctg, chunk = T)

# 3. Set some processing options.
# For this small single file example, the chunk size is 100 m + 10 m of buffer
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 10
opt_chunk_size(ctg)   <- 100            # Small because this is a dummy example.
opt_chunk_alignment(ctg) <- c(-50, -35) # Align such as it creates 2 chunks only.
opt_select(ctg)       <- "xyz"          # Read only the coordinates.
opt_filter(ctg)       <- "-keep_first"  # Read only first returns.
plot(ctg, chunk = T)

# 4. Apply a user-defined function to take advantage of the internal engine
opt    <- list(need_buffer = TRUE,   # catalog_apply will throw an error if buffer = 0
               automerge   = TRUE)   # catalog_apply will merge the outputs into a single object
output <- catalog_apply(ctg, my_tree_detection_method, ws = 5, .options = opt)

plot(output)

When I run the line with the catalog_apply() function, I get the following error message:
Erreur : The function is tested before starting processing the collection and failed with following error:
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : impossible de trouver une méthode héritée pour la fonction ‘is.empty’ pour la signature ‘"LAS"’

And the las object seems empty, just like the chunk object:
las
class        : LAS (v1.0 format 1)
memory       : 816 bytes 
extent       : Inf, -Inf, Inf, -Inf (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref.  : NA 
area         : 0 units²
points       : 0  points
density      : 0 points/units²
Messages d'avis :
1: Dans min(x) : aucun argument trouvé pour min ; Inf est renvoyé
2: Dans max(x) : aucun argument pour max ; -Inf est renvoyé
3: Dans min(x) : aucun argument trouvé pour min ; Inf est renvoyé
4: Dans max(x) : aucun argument pour max ; -Inf est renvoyé`

> chunk_temp
class   : LAScluster
name    : noname 
center  : 0 , 0 
extent  : 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
extent+ : 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
size    : 0 x 0 
files   : example.laz 
filter  : -inside 0 0 0 0 

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thank you for your understanding.
Francis
I've tried with a reproducible example.

terra also defines is.empty. Maybe there is a clash in namespace. Did you try lidR::is.empty()?
